# JSON posting operation converts object values to string type

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have an object containing a date object. When I post it to a NodeJS server, it's still an object but the time has been converted to a string. Is there any way to avoid this? I can't parse the entire object because I get an "Unexpected token o" error (I assume because it's still an object).

Before:

```
Object {title: " - fd", start: Tue Feb 11 2014 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), end: Tue Feb 11 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), allDay: false, id: ""…}
```

After:

```
Object
allDay: "false"
end: "Tue Feb 11 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"
id: ""
room: "Shower 1"
start: "Tue Feb 11 2014 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"
title: " - fd"
```

Comment: Show us the values *before* and *after*

Comment: The JavaScript Object Notation does not support the Date type, as you can see at http://json.org/ .
A little bit of logic in the marshalling and unmarshalling of the data is needed.

Comment: I am really not sure how to go about POSTing an object containing a date, if JSON does not support it... any ideas?

Comment: still_learning postead a valid approach. The receiver could transform the number back to a Date.
Another way could be defining a schema (if you use mongoose, for example) and istantiating an object from the request body. 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: How are you converting to and from JSON? I am wondering because it looks like the boolean value `false` is turning into the string `"false"`.

Comment: @mcrumley I assemble the object like `var object = { stuff }` and then just `$.ajax({POST})` with `dataType: "json"`

Comment: You will probably want to convert that back to a bool on the server, since everything is sent as a string. That is the same reason you need the `+myDate` for still_learning's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include `Date` objects in JSON. You can convert them to a number and back to a date on the server:

```
// Convert Date to number on client side
objToSend.foo.myDate = objToSend.foo.myDate.getTime();

// Convert number to date on server side
objReceived.foo.myDate = new Date(+objReceived.foo.myDate);
```

That requires your application to know which properties are dates and which are not.

Comment: When I do this, I get a value of null for the conversion back to date. I used the same commands you did

Comment: So `console.log(objReceived.foo.myDate)` prints a valid positive integer?

Comment: Yes, but when I do `new Date(property)` it prints `Invalid Date`.

Comment: Try `new Date(+property)`. That'll convert `property` to a `Number` first.

Comment: Actually I used parseInt but I assume they are either equivalent or do more or less the same thing.

Comment: They are equivalent if the string is a valid base-10 integer.

Comment: @erythraios They are **not** equivalent but `parseInt` is actually pretty similar (assuming you use base 10) and even better in this case (`+property` would allow `property` to be a float).